# Firebase valueEventListener doesn't return in order

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've created a chat apps with following structure on firebase :

```
Project
.
....Chats
.  .
.  ....chat-01
.  .  .
.  .  ....author : "john@example.com"
.  .  .
.  .  ....content : "hi"
.  .  .
.  .  ....time_created : "12-12-2017 22:30:00"
.  .
.  ....chat-02
.  .  .
.  .  ....author : "alice@example.com"
.  .  .
.  .  ....content : "hello, how are you ?"
.  .  .
.  .  ....time_created : "12-12-2017 22:31:00"
.  .
.  ....chat-03
.     .
.     ....author : "john@example.com"
.     .
.     ....content : "hi"
.     .
.     ....time_created : "12-12-2017 22:32:00"
.
....chatgroups
   .
   ....chatgroup-1
      .
      ....chats
         .
         ....chat-01 : 1
         .
         ....chat-02 : 1
         .
         ....chat-03 : 1
```

The way I retrieve the chat is :

```
public void getChatrooms(){
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ref.child("chatgroups").child("chatgroup-1").child("chats").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        Iterator iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = (DataSnapshot)iterator.next();
            getChatDetails(dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }
    }
    });
}

public void getChatDetails(String key){
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ref.child("chats").child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
            System.out.println(dataSnapshot.child("content").getValue().toString())
        }
        });
}
```

The problem is this piece of code return the chat in order of : **chat-01,chat-03,chat-02.** It has the behavior to order by the author of chat. Because when I change **chat-01** author to "alice@example.com", it return in order of : **chat-01,chat-02,chat-03** , but If I add **chat-04** with "alice@example.com" as author to both chats and chatgroups, it will return : **chat-01,chat-02,chat-04,chat-03.** I don't know if the problem were caused by the async callback or firebase default order. My question is how to make it return as in the structure order?

Comment: you can use orderByChild(time_created)

Comment: @LakshayJuneja tried that, doesn't work

Comment: if it doesn't work then you can use to implementing Comparable interface on your object to sort list with respect to time_created.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions here. One solution would be to query your database using an [ordering method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), and this would be `orderByChild(time_created)` method. The second approach would be to change the key nodes from `chat-01`, `chat-02` and so on, into unique keys that are generated by the `push()` method. This push ids are based on time and generated entirely on the client without consultation with the server. This is a common practice within Firebase.